# Can a 2NF database already be in 3NF?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm doing a homework question where I have to convert a database to 1NF, 2NF and 3NF.  I have gotten to 2NF and it does not appear to have any transitive dependencies.  Does that mean that it is already in 3NF?

Comment: Please google your title. Also, you probably have seen a definition of 3NF that mentions 2NF.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding that you can normalize a relation to 2NF *and no higher*, then to 3NF *and no higher*. Normalization doesn't work that way. You might normalize a relation aiming to remove a partial key dependency (aiming for 2NF), and then find the resulting relations are in 5NF.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When a relation (variable or value) is in a given normal form it can also be in higher normal forms at the same time. (But beware that sometimes people sloppily say that a relation is in a given normal form but they *mean* that it's in that normal form but also *not* any higher one.)

Being in a normal form is a property of a relation. The way they are named, 1-2-3-BCNF-4-5 are stricter and stricter conditions. So when a relation meets one of those conditions it meets all the preceding ones and it might meet later ones. You happen to have a 2NF relation that is also a 3NF relation. Or to put that anther way, you have a 3NF relation that, *like every 3NF relation is also in 2NF*. You just happened to notice that it was in 2NF *before* you noticed it was in 3NF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless you missed a transitive functional dependency.